# SQL - Count Duplicate Values Within Date Range

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple, but large, database that I need to write a SQL statement for. The statements needs to do the following:

1. Get the 15 most popular values for a field.
2. From those 15, get the count that value has appeared within a particular time period.

My table contains both a `Date` and a `Value` field. I am able to extract the 15 most popular values, or get the count for a particular value in a given time period. I do not know how to put the two together.

This is my current SQL:

```
SELECT
    Count( Value ) AS Total,
    Value AS Value 
FROM
    Database
GROUP BY
    Value 
ORDER BY
    Total DESC 
    LIMIT 15
```

That will get my most popular 15. But from that, I want to display the `COUNT()` that each `Value` is between two dates.

Would this require a `HAVING` clause?

Comment: You need a conditional sum: Try `SELECT
    sum(case when date between x and y then Value else 0 end) AS Total`

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the previous solution (which would also do a job) a little bit:

```
SELECT
  Value,
  Count(*) as TotalInPeriod
FROM Database 
WHERE Value in (SELECT Value FROM Database GROUP BY Value 
                ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 15) 
  AND date_field BETWEEN your_start_date and your_end_date
GROUP BY Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Make an inner query that finds the top 15 values overall, and join it to the main set to limit it to those values.

```
SELECT
  Count( Value) as TotalInPeriod,
  Value as Value
FROM
  Database a
JOIN (SELECT
        Count( Value ) AS Total,
        Value AS Value 
      FROM
        Database
      GROUP BY
        Value 
      ORDER BY
        Total DESC 
        LIMIT 15) as topValues
ON
  a.Value = topValues.Value
WHERE
  a.date_field BETWEEN your_start_date and your_end_date
GROUP BY
  a.Value
```